# how to display proper massage in adf

Tags: java, oracle-adf

how can i display this in friendly way don't what to show ora like this https://community.oracle.com/message/13376887#13376887 am in jdeveloper 11.1.1.9.0

i did this 37.8.1 How to Customize Base ADF Business Components Error Messages
Assume you want to customize the builtin error message:
JBO-27014: Attribute Name is Product is required
If you have requested the Oracle ADF source code from Oracle Worldwide Support, you can look in the CSMessageBundle.java file in the oracle.jbo package to see that this error message is related to the combination of the following lines in that message bundle file:

```
    public class CSMessageBundle extends CheckedListResourceBundle {
      // etc.
      public static final String EXC_VAL_ATTR_MANDATORY            = "27014";
      // etc. 
      private static final Object[][] sMessageStrings = {
        // etc.
        {EXC_VAL_ATTR_MANDATORY, "Attribute {2} in {1} is required"},
        // etc.
      }
    }

37.8.1 How to Customize Base ADF Business Components Error Messages
Assume you want to customize the builtin error message:
JBO-27014: Attribute Name is Product is required
If you have requested the Oracle ADF source code from Oracle Worldwide Support, you can look in the CSMessageBundle.java file in the oracle.jbo package to see that this error message is related to the combination of the following lines in that message bundle file:
public class CSMessageBundle extends CheckedListResourceBundle {
  // etc.
  public static final String EXC_VAL_ATTR_MANDATORY            = "27014";
  // etc. 
  private static final Object[][] sMessageStrings = {
    // etc.
    {EXC_VAL_ATTR_MANDATORY, "Attribute {2} in {1} is required"},
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: am not able to see the message after I have done this